# How to make a css element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how I can make a class in JavaScript type dot using CSS properties.

This is the CSS code that I have in HTML:

```
.dot3 {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is what I am trying in JavaScript:

```
.dot2 {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var val = childSnapshot.val();
            //content +='<tr>';

            if (val.Distancem2 > 15 &&  val.DistanceMiddle1 > 15 && val.DistanceMiddle3 > 15){

                content +='<div>';
                content += '<span>' +class="dot2"+'</span>';
;
                content +='</div>';
            }

        });
        $('#div').append(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery and make use of .addClass()

Comment: Hello @Vammer welcome to SO, Please try to explain your questions, with examples of what do you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
content += '<span class="dot2"></span>';
```

I also don't think append works like that, but you need to create the element first with `document.createElement('div')` and then append the element, but I guess you can just use `innerHTML` instead for your solution:

```
$('#div').innerHTML += content;
```

Comment: Do not work. My new code is:  content +='<div>';
     content += '<span class="dot2"></span>';
       content +='</div>';
    }
    
    });
           $('#div').innerHTML += content;

Comment: And you're aware that your CSS code is .dot3 and not .dot2? I'm not that into creating CSS code throught javascript, but if you really want to do it, you need to use `createElement` and create a STYLE element, add CSS  to it through `innerHTML`, and append the STYLE element to the HEAD. I will flag this thread with a link to another thread with a similar question.

Comment: The .dot 3 is in the HTML and in javascript is .dot2 I want the element .dot2 to be created through javascript and not HTML